# OpenWRT: Create Standalone (i.e. not connected to Internet) Network Using Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: openwrt

Trying to configure OpenWRT as a standalone wireless network (i.e. not connected to the Internet) on Raspberry Pi Zero W to make a portable network for some smart plugs that connect via WPS. Will do Home Assistant on another Pi.

Followed [this post](https://bmorton.com/posts/pi-zero-wifi-bridge/) and was able to get OpenWRT to work. In order to set things up as called for in the cited post, I connected a USB hub to the Pi Zero W to provide ethernet and a second wireless adapter.

However, in production I don't want to have to use the USB hub, and instead rely solely on the Pi's internal wireless adapter to provide all networking.

So, how do I modify the existing configuration to do the following?

- Eliminate the USB ethernet adapter (which means that I will no longer have the DHCP server provided by my home router)
- Eliminate the USB wireless adapter (since no need to connect as client to home router)
- Ensure that the remaining wireless network runs a DHCP server

I read Ben Scott's answer in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701184/openwrt-concept-of-interfaces-devices-and-wireless) regarding the OpenWRT concepts of device, radio, interface and network but it's just not clicking.

Is it possible to configure what I need from LuCI or must it be done from the command line? If command line, what files must be modified?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why a separate Pi for these two functionalities? A wireless access point for low data rates definitely won't overtask a RPi running home Assistant.

Comment: Run both OpenWRT and Home Assistant on a Zero W that has only 512 Mb of RAM?

Comment: that sounds like a lot of RAM to me.